# How to use a Filter?

Tags: java, servlets, servlet-filters

When does a Java Filter start? Does the Filter `init()` method overide the servlet `init()` method? Where do I declare the init parameters in `web.xml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *When does a Java Filter start?*

During startup of the webapplication.

---

> *Does the Filter `init()` method overide the servlet `init()` method?*

No. They are in no way related to each other. The `init()` method of **your** filter just implements the one as definied in [`javax.servlet.Filter` interface](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/Filter.html).

---

> *Where do I declare the init parameters in `web.xml`?*

Inside the `<filter>` declaration.

```xml
<filter>
    <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
    <filter-class>com.example.MyFilter</filter-class>
    <init-param>
        <param-name>foo</param-name>
        <param-value>bar</param-value>
    </init-param> 
</filter>
```

It'll then be available inside `init()` as follows:

```
@Override
public void init(FilterConfig config) {
    String foo = config.getInitParameter("foo"); // contains "bar".
}
```

Comment: that means that the request will be filtered automaticaly i mean i dont have o put start order, it's also the same in response???

Comment: @giorgo - You will have to add filter-mapping to the URLs that you want to apply the filter to. For example to apply filter to a page called checkOut.JSP you would do this:  <filter-mapping>
     <filter-name>myFilter</filter-name>
     <url-pattern>/secure/checkOut.jsp</url-pattern>
   </filter-mapping>

Comment: The filter will intercept only on requests which matches the `<url-pattern>` which you specify yourself in `<filter-mapping>`. To learn more about filters, please check [our `servlet-filters` info page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/servlet-filters) (to get it the next time, hover the mouse over `[servlet-filter]` tag and press `info` link or just press the tag and click "about the servlet-filters tag" link).

Answer (score 1):

Declare it in web.xml like

```
<web-app version=...>
    ...
    <filter>
        <description>...</description>
        <display-name>My Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>com.foo.bar.MyFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>
    ...
    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>MyFilter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/some/path</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>
    ...
</web-app>
```

**[Update]** The `<filter>` section registers your filter to the system; it will be automatically started up when the web app is started. In the `<filter-mapping>` section you can configure when (on what URLs) to invoke your filter. **[/Update]**

The rest of your questions is already answered by @BalusC.

Comment: thank you very much i didn't know how to start up a filter but if it  start with the Webapp then i only have to write the filter???

Comment: You will have to write your filter unless you are applying a filter that is defined in a third party jar file.